# Need to develop a model for measuring inter-annual and seasonal variability in pasture cover using modis 16 day composites

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, remote-sensing, envi, geostatistical-analyst

Aiming to use statistical methods in ArcGis and Envi image analysis to measure inter-annual and seasonal variability in paster cover using MODIS 16 day composite image from 2000-2014.

Quite stuck on where to start and need any information or links to papers or previous analysis' of a similar style.

Answer (score 1):

The USGS phenology project might inspire you a little.

http://phenology.cr.usgs.gov/other_resources.php

Comment: Some description/summary of what the project is or the short version of its analysis method could improve this answer. Also, your link goes to the 'other resources' page - is that intentional, or should it go to the main home page? If it is supposed to be the other resources, you could describe the link as meeting the request by going to a collection of other papers/analysis (though again, a summary is best to avoid a 'link only' answer that may go dead in the future).